# Power BI change formatting integer to decimal

Tags: powerbi, integer, format, powerquery

I have a simple question but  i am already stuck for a hour to solve this.

The use case:

I have a column called year and it read the value from a sql view table. the column jaar has a column type decimal.

In Power BI the data is read as a Whole Number. I would like to change the formatting like the following example:

from 36180  into 36.180
39565 into 39.565
and so on....

Any suggestions to do this with Power Query Editor?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In powerquery, click select the column and use

Transform ... standard ... divide .... 1000

[image]

Comment: Second this. You'll have to delete the original column as a next step, unless you want to keep it.

Comment: I am transforming the column, not duplicating it. You don't have an extra column to delete with this change

Comment: My bad. :) You're completely right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a decimal point instead of a thousands separator, divide the column by 1000 in Power Query or a DAX calculated column or  measure,eg

```
Aantak K = sum('Table'[Aantal])/1000
```

It's a common practice to create measures and hide the base columns in the report view.

Or for the measure or base column you can use a [custom format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-custom-format-strings)

So for 12345 this one:

```
#,##,.000
```

Will scale it to thousands

12.345

And this one

```
#,##,.000 K
```

will scale and add the unit so

12.345 K

Comment: I don't think a separator is what they're after, I think they want a true decimal.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps.  I updated the answer for that case too.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. your proposal regarding creating a measure and create a custom formatting on the modelling page works!

Answer (score 0):

the solution was creating a measure for field Aantal and create a custom format for this measure on Modelling tab.